# Pass Date from View to Controller with JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to pass the date by ajax to controller as below:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '/UserReport/GenerateReport',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'clientId': $('#reportClientDropdown').val(),
                    'dateFrom': $('#datePickerFrom').val(),
                    'dateTo': $('#datePickerTo').val()
                }),
                success: function (succ) {
                    //
                    },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
```

dateFrom and dateTo are in format dd/mm/yyyy.

I am getting 500 error after this call. Here is my controller

```
public JsonResult GenerateReport(int userId, int clientId, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
```

Is there a problem with DateTime parameter?

Comment: Is the culture on the server one that has a format `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: You should also use your browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response - it will have the error details.

Comment: POST http://localhost:xxxx/UserReport/GenerateReport 500 (Internal Server Error) status 500

Comment: don't forget to add `[HttpPost]` attribute on `GenerateReport` action

Comment: You have already stated its a 500 error - no need to repeat it in the comments. Debug your code!

Comment: your controller takes `userId` but your code does not send it.

Comment: The name of the data parameter in json and in C# must be exactly the same.

Comment: Why dont you make your parameter string and then convert it to datetime? you can then convert it to datetime, this way you will have more control over it rather than letting the framework decide on the format and stuff

Answer (score 0):

specify ajax request datatype  [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/UserReport/GenerateReport',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
                    'userId': 1,
                    'clientId': $('#reportClientDropdown').val(),
                    'dateFrom': $('#datePickerFrom').val(),
                    'dateTo': $('#datePickerTo').val()
                }),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
     },
   error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
     }
});
```